# Free WPF Carousel Implementation

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have seen a lot of Carousels to show off WPF.  I have never really need one before now though.

Is there a decent free one?

I have access to the Dev Express one, but I am making an open source project and would rather not put code in it that others cannot easily compile.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I've been looking for one too, I've found various paid for ones, but I've never seen one in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: You are right.  I should have looked closer.  That was the afore mentioned Dev Express Item.  Thanks double checking.  I removed the text that was incorrect from my question.

Answer (score 17):

After some searching, I (re)found the free and fabulous [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) (http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/)

It has many controls that are great.  One of them is the [ElementFlow](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=145).  This control has many great views methods.  One of them is the [Carousel](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=211) view.

(Just as a side note, after looking at them all I think I like the VForm and CoverFlow views best.  They are kind of a carousel like view, but can handle a lot of items with out needing resizing.)