# Looking for an image rotator similar to WPF Carousel

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rotation, carousel

Is there a good article or source code where I could find an WPF image rotator (moves automatically) similar to WPF carousel?

I'm not really interested with [DevExpress Carousel Control for WPF](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/A7E8B9D6-F6F3-47B5-BF00-690F954B2A06). I'm only looking for a simpler approach for this one.

Comment: Have you considered writing your own? They aren't exactly complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer to this very similar StackOverflow question: [Free WPF Carousel Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124942/free-wpf-carousel-implementation)