# Image sliding control using wpf

Tags: wpf, image, slider

I want to create a slider with images like a control in the bottom of the youtube(floating images with left and right navigation button). How i have to start. i am new to wpf.

for example: http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/page/4/

Geetha.

Comment: Did u got the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to start anything is just to start right away. Even if you don't know how to start... Just write the first line of code. Let it be awful. Hardcode images. Use dirty tricks. Then throw it away and rewrite.

Along with writing the code read a lot. There are [dozens of books on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940143/xaml-wpf-book-recommendation/1940258) out there. [MSDN sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) are awesome.

Don't forget to read the code too. This technique is extremely helpful. You can find good [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124942/free-wpf-carousel-implementation/2126339#2126339) of [carousel implementation](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+carousel).

Hope this helps.