# click-slide UI for WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, animation

We have a WPF app where we'll have a collection of photos. We'd like the user to be able to scroll through them using the now-ubiquitous method seen on iPhones and Androids where you select the list of things and slide it over... the speed at which you slide determines the number of items you navigate through.

Is there an existing third-party WPF control that can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be useful for you.  A free carousel implementation:

[Free WPF Carousel Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124942/free-wpf-carousel-implementation)

Devexpress also has a [carousel](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Carousel/dependency_properties.xml), but I'm not sure the cost.