# Animated view switching wpf

Tags: wpf, animation, user-interface

I'm trynig to create an animated interface with sliding like [that](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx). 
Can you give me some ideas how to realize this feature on wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you are looking for is call a carousel. You can find implementations via these related questions:

[Free WPF Carousel Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124942/free-wpf-carousel-implementation)

[click-slide UI for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332339/click-slide-ui-for-wpf)

Comment: Finally I found FluidKIT library and TransitionPresenter control inside. Thank you.